# Trouble with a jqueryui accordion tied to knockoutjs inside a jqueryui modal dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a modal dialog (jqueryui) that contains an accordion (jqueryui).  The accordion is data-bound using knockoutjs to an observableArray.

Here is my code and a sample of whats happening

http://jsbin.com/ebocew/3/edit#javascript,html,live

Basically, the first time you click on the Show Dialog button, the dialog displays and the accordion looks like it is supposed to.  However, if you close the dialog and click the Add Item button, an item is added to the knockoutjs list.  This in turn adds another accordion element, but now if you display the dialog, the accordion details are not sized appropriately.

What do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I may have found a workaround.  I'm not completely thrilled with it but it may get me moving forward.  I added `$(element).find("div").height("auto");` in the accordion handler update and that causes it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody else had any other suggestions to offer, I'll list my "hack" as the solution.  Basically, I noticed that for some reason the div of my accordion content kept getting assigned a height of 0px.  So, in my accordion binder, I added:

```
$(element).find("div").height("auto");
```

That seemed to fix my issues.  Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the # from the 'id' as below

```
<div data-bind="attr: { id: 'collapsible' + testitem.ID }" class="accordion-body collapse">
```

Comment: I'm not clear on the context of your answer.  I went to the jsbin link provided by the OP but didn't see anything that remotely resembled your solution.  Could you post your complete solution please?  Thanks!